# How can I detect LTE/WCDMA cell ID changes in android?

Tags: android

Currently I am using the following listeners: PhoneStateListener and BroadcastReceiver.
I am not able to detect the change in LTE/WCDMA cell ID and propagate it to my app using these.

Does Android support the cell ID change indication?
Is there any other way to detect the cell ID changes in Android?
(I am using API level > 17 as is required by Android documentation)